# SQLAlchemy session.merge throws "Cannot update identity column"

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I have entries in DB table with columns: task_id, userstory_id, state, assigned_to_mail

task_id is primary key

now i am trying to update those entries, i mean i get tasks again and if there is no task_id, add it to table but if task_id already exist just update changed fields (task_id will never be changed)

i am trying to do this with session.merge() and then in try except i am doing session.commit()

But i get `Cannot update identity column 'task_id'.`

I found somewhere that session.merge() should update only changed fields and should not throm identity exceptions.

```
def put_task(
    session: Any,
    parameters: dict[Any, Any],
) -> Any:
[...]
new_task = models.AzureTaskModel(
        task_id=parameters["task_id"],
        userstory_id=parameters["userstory_id"],
        state=parameters["state"],
        assigned_to_mail=parameters["assigned_to_mail"].lower()
    )
session.merge(instance=new_task)
    try:
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(
            "Error during creating Task %s : %s",
            new_task.task_id,
            e,
        )
    return new_task
```